# Localização container docker no host

Tags: linux, docker

Desde que comecei utilizar o docker ano passado, para acessar diretamente os arquivos do meu container eu usava os seguintes passos:

- docker inspect -f ´{{.Id}}´ container_id

Ele me retorna o container id completo

Com o container id completo eu acessava o diretório onde os arquivos do container estavam localizados:

- cd /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/container_id_completo

Só que atualmente quando faço isso retorna: arquivo ou diretório não encontrado.
Verifiquei que na pasta mnt existem dezenas de dietórios com nomes de ids completos mas nenhum deles é de containers recentes.

Tentei ver se encontrava o diretório usando o comando:

- find -name container_id_completo

mas não encontra nenhuma pasta

Alguém sabe dizer se o docker fez alguma modificação em relação a isso em suas últimas atualizações e caso sim como eu posso fazer para acessar os arquivos do container de forma direta através do host?

**SO: Linux Mint 17.3 64bits**

**Docker: 1.10.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/#containers), a partir da versão `1.10` os nomes dos diretórios em que os *containers* são localizados dentro do *host* não são iguais às IDs dos *containers*.

E os *filesystems* dos *containers* ficam dentro de `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/`.

Eu até fiz um teste para ver se conseguiria encontrar meu *container* dentro desse diretório `diff/`, e qual seria o nome do diretório. A ID do meu *container* sendo executado:

```
"Id": "099bc297959fb860f5190f9d14d518071ef9626efd941215e28d054382750f6d"
```

e no entando, o *filesystem* desse *container* foi montado em:

```
/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/7864538e8d46047fc57bcf618472a42972b7e377335dd09695eea1ddf0003676
```

*(sei que é o mesmo container porque eu coloquei um arquivo de texto qualquer dentro dele, e vi que ele se encontrava nesse caminho dentro do host)*

**SO: Ubuntu 14.04 64bits**

**Docker: 1.10.3**

Comment: É, depois realizando mais testes eu encontrei meu conteiner no diretório aufs, dei um ls -lt e deduzi qual era pela data de criação e la ele estava mas com um nome diferente da ID do container como era antes, não sei o porque dessa mudança, talvez questão de segurança, ou pra dificultar o acesso direto as pastas via host, de toda forma achei a mudança desnecessária.